# Why is clang confusing Boost for STL?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, header, clang

I'm trying to compile a C++ library (which compiles fine in g++) with Clang.

However for some reason I am getting errors everywhere I use an stl container.  The error message seems to suggest it thinks I am trying to use a boost set, which I don't think I am.

I don't believe anywhere I somehow aliased `boost` as `std`, and I never actually use the `using` keyword.

```
/Users/zennatavares/repos/cliques/cliques/../cliques/structures/disjointset.h:140:8: error: too few template arguments for class template 'set'
                std::set<int> visited_parents_;
                     ^
/usr/local/include/boost/detail/container_fwd.hpp:90:64: note: template is declared here
    template <class Key, class Compare, class Allocator> class set;
```

Comment: and thats why we dont use the using statement to bring entire namespaces into our code.  Remove the using statement and use the full name "std::set" instead.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Um, what `using` statement? He's explicitly qualifying it as `std::set` in his code (or at least, the line that clang repeats).

Comment: That being said, a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) would be appreciated. You may have a `using` statement somewhere you're not aware of.

Comment: @MooingDuck, Thanks but I am not sure why you wrote this and have been upvoted since I explicitly stated I am not using 'using', as shown in the code snippet. I am not sure what example to show, as this happens every place I have used any stl container.  I have grepped all my code base to ensure there are no using statements.

Comment: My appologies, the using issue is very very common, and makes errors that look very similar to yours.  The more I read your error, the more I think barnes53 is right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that the issue is boost trying to forward declare members of namespace std, and Boost is getting the forward declaration wrong for libc++. There's not any portable way to do such forward declarations so boost really shouldn't be doing it. Declaring things inside namespace std results in undefined behavior.

Here's a bug filed against boost for one of these issues. https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5197

If you post a complete program that reproduces the issue then perhaps we can give more detail on what exactly you can do to fix this in your case.